# javac is not recognized as internal command

Tags: java, netbeans

My current system config is -

- Netbeans 12.0
- JDK 14.0.2
- Windows 10 (64bit)

1. I have added the environmental variable in PATH manually i.e. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin.
2. I tried adding using cmd as well. As well as adding the JAVA_HOME as a new variable with value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2 .
   [image]
3. I have used the set command to do this process i.e. set path = "%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin". Also, I have used the same command without the set keyword.
4. Since javah command was deprecated for versions of jdk>8, I have tried to use javac -h command as well.
5. I have also tried to install JDK v. 8.0.2 instead of the current one.
6. Although there's no javah.exe file in the bin folder, there is however javac.exe file.
7. I have uninstalled and reinstalled JDK and Netbeans quite a few times.

I am currently working on JNI with Netbeans IDE and C/C++ plugin. (I have successfully installed Cygwin and necessary extension for the file to build. Although I don't know how they affect this problem, still I thought I should add this).
The command I wish to use with 'javah' is the one used for creating a C header from a Java class i.e. 'javah -o JNIDemoJava.h -classpath JNIDemoJava/build/classes jnidemojava.Main'.

But due to this error, I have been stuck for a few days. Please do assist.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following way you can set Path variable **temporary**(it can only be used in the same  command line):

You should do it this way:(notice =)

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin
```

And if you set JAVA_HOME variable correctly you can do it this way:

```
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

For setting this permanently read this post :

https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

**We should know the reason for this**

1. Our OS comes with a predefined (built-in)set of tools and utilities. When we try to execute the command `e.g. cls`  in the Windows command line then OS knows about it as it is pre-defined, and command get executed.
2. However, when we install any third party tool/software then we need to update **path** variable so that OS can refer to it's binary for execution.
3. When we install different versions of java on your system then installations go to different directories. E.g. *JDK* installation directory for Windows will be
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`
4. Similarly, *JRE* installation directory for Windows will be JDK installation directory for Windows will be
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161`
5. We need to update the path variable of OS to point to the appropriate directory. If we set the path of JDK then it will execute a binary from JDK bin directory.

**Solution**

- we need to update `JDK` or `JRE` version specific directory location into `PATH` Environment variable.
- In this case use
  `set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin` to set JAVA_PATH

Comment: Poor example. `cls` isn't an external command at all, it is built into the shell. No binary, and nothing to do with the `PATH` whatsoever.